# Usage of static inline to functions which calls other larger functions in C

Tags: c, gcc, static, inline, compiler-optimization

Say I have a function,

```
static inline int res( int x )
{
  /** total() is a large func */
  int processedPkts = total();
  return ( processedPkts + x);
}

int total()
{
   /** Where the function total() does lot of processing,counting no of packets 
    or say, it has many lines of code */
}
```

So, my question is, can I use static inline for `res()` function which in-turn calls larger functions?

As per my understanding on why/when to use inline,

> it encourages the compiler to build the function into the code where it is used (generally with the goal of improving execution speed).

> static inline is usually used with small functions that are better done in the calling routine than by using a call mechanism, simply because they are so short and fast that actually doing them is better than calling a separate copy.

So, at assembly level, `total()` function is unaffected (uses regular call mechanism) by static inline, and therefore it is recommended to use static inline for `res()` ?

Comment: What don't you understand? Without the `inline`, your code would call a function that then calls another function; with the `inline`, that first call is effectively removed and the code that calls the second function is added as inline code.

Comment: Inlining is just a suggestion, as given answer says already – maybe more important are other impacts: If you provide the function implementation in the header, the `total` function must be publicly available there, too, so you cannot hide it away (access control) by making it `static` any more.

Comment: @AdrianMole with `inline`, when you say, "code  that calls the second function is added as `inline` code", does it mean, code present in `total()` will also be inlined ? because you said its added as inline code.

Comment: Only the code of the function declared `inline` is actually inlined, assuming the compiler follows the suggestion. `total` is totally independent from, for that one the decision if being inlined or not will be made on its own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not matter. The function `total` will not be probably inlined (normal function call will be emitted). Function `res` probably will be inlined.

Why probably. Because the `inline` keyword is only a suggestion. Functions without inline may be inlined as well. The compiler may inline the `total` function as well if decides that on a certain level of optimization it will result in the best code generation.

Many compilers have special extensions which give you control over inlining. for example:

gcc has `__attribute__((noinline))` and `__attribute__((always_inline))`.

iar `#pragma inline=never` and `pragma inline=force`

Comment: I *think* the OP is asking if the `res()` function can be inlined, even though it itself calls another function that won't be inlined.

Comment: @AdrianMole changed the answer.